# Network Access Control with Linux

Tags: linux, networking, 802.1

Are there any projects to provide NAC support in Linux? My main aim is to accept/deny access to other network on a Linux Firewall after asking the operating systems' NAC agents about the client's health.

For example: *if the client has no antivirus installed, this Linux will block the client's traffic*.

Some switches have such capabilities. Is it possible in Linux?

Comment: are the clients running windows or linux or???

Comment: mostly windows.

Comment: Possibly of interest? http://www.opennac.org/opennac/en.html

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are looking for [packetfence](http://www.packetfence.org/)... it runs under Linux...

> PacketFence is a fully supported, trusted, Free and Open Source network access control (NAC) solution. Boasting an impressive feature set including a captive-portal for registration and remediation, centralized wired and wireless management, powerful guest management options, 802.1X support, layer-2 isolation of problematic devices; PacketFence can be used to effectively secure networks small to very large heterogeneous networks.

You need to use [packetfence](http://www.packetfence.org/) + [nessus](http://www.nessus.org/) ([nessus wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nessus_%28software%29)) to enforce anti-virus policy

Comment: How can it check the all antivirus signatures are installed on the client? AFAIK, there is a protocol to talk with end user agents for checking. Does packetfence supports it?

Comment: There's not one protocol for that communication: each NAC system has its own. You probably need an agent on the clients, or an application with credentials on those clients, to test AV levels.